# remove an element that is before the selected element

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm doing some form error handling/manipulation and I have the need to remove an error div that is before the input that is being validated...

HTML:

```
<p><div class="textError"></div><input type="text" name="someInputField" /></p>
```

I'd like to remove the div.textError if the input field is validated.  I tried this...

`$(this).before('<div class="textError"></div>').remove('<div class="textError"></div>');`

and no dice.  any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `before` method adds something.  To get a relative use the `prev` method.  So something like this:

```
$(this)
  .prev('div.textError')
  .remove()
  .end()
.before('<div class="textError"></div>');
```